# information_schema_stats_expiry = troll en MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo la siguiente situacion, estoy usando `MySQL` y `phpMyadmin` para manejar mi base de datos, luego para obtener el `AUTO_INCREMENT` de una tabla uso el siguiente query:

```
SELECT LPAD(`AUTO_INCREMENT`,4,0) as AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATA_BASE_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Este dato lo uso en otro script php, pero despues de varias actualizaciones del Servidor el Mysql en su version 5.7 o superior, me esta troleando en cada actualizacion tengo que ir y ejecutar este otro query, para desactivar el cache de `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

```
SET GLOBAL information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
```

tambien note que esta configuracion afecta que muestra el `phpmyadmin` en la pestaña de operaciones de cada tabla...

**mi pregunta es de que otra forma puedo obtener estos datos y evitar recurrir a `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?**

Comment: Porque querrias saber el auto_increment de una tabla? si algo depende de eso, esta mal... igual, ojo, que las configuraciones de phpmyadmin no tienen nada que ver a veces con la de la base de datos...

Comment: Porque querria saber el auto_increment: no se para que usa el dato pero forma parte del script y no puedo llegar y eliminarlo si es lo que me vaz a sugerir, la pregunta es como obtenerlo de otra forma si existe otra forma...

Comment: no no.. lo raro es que se use ese dato para algo.. pero bueno.. raro que no te deje acceder al schema o que devuelva basura... esperemos a alguien que la tenga mas claro...

Comment: @gbianchi es pro esto: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry
The information_schema_stats_expiry session variable defines the period of time before cached statistics expire. The default is 86400 seconds (24 hours), but the time period can be extended to as much as one year.

Comment: Pero.. el autoincrement de la tabla cambia?? no es siempre el mismo lo que incrementa???

Comment: claro que cambia con los insert; pero al hacer la consulta de como esta el AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA me vota un numero inferior XD

Comment: el problema no es que si se actualiza el AUTO_INCREMENT, el problema es la consulta que retorna un dato basado en la cache, por el cache que genera information_schema_stats_expiry  ...

Comment: @gbianchi todo esta bien el problema es el query segun encontre parece que antes de usar la tabla de INFORMATION_SCHEMA se debe usar esto para que actualice la estadistica: `ANALYZE TABLE 'TABLENAME';`

Comment: Te iba a sugerir `SHOW TABLE STATUS` pero funciona igual, depende de `SET information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;`  Posiblemente no tengas solución, en mi experiencia, las columnas autonumericas, escapan bastante al control del desarrollador. ¿Y cual sería el problema de setear la expiración al principio de tu script?

Comment: que luego de las actualizaciones toca volver a colocar el = 0

Comment: al parecer la solucion es o poner eso en cada actualizacion o colocar antes de los script que usan esta funcionalidad el query que actualiza la estadiscitca: 
`ANALYZE TABLE 'TABLE_NAME'; ` pero no se si esto estaria catalogado como solucion ....

Comment: @PatricioMoracho que opinas